# Query with line breaks fails to execute in PowerShell

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell

I'm using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO assembly to automate some database tasks in PowerShell.  For some reason executing a query with a line break doesn't seem to work.  However, I've also reproduced the exact same task in C# and it does work.  I'm not sure if there's a subtle difference that I've been overlooking or if there's some odd difference with reading a file in PowerShell that is causing me an issue.  Below is all the information needed to reproduce:

SQL Script (test.sql):

```
select
* from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

PowerShell (**doesn't** work):

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'

$server = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server('serverName')
$database = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database($server, 'myDatabase')
$setupScript = Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\scripts\test.sql"
$database.ExecuteNonQuery($setupScript)
```

Here's the error message PowerShell gives:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "1" argument(s):
>   "ExecuteNonQuery failed for Database 'Salesforce-Neptune'. " --->
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException:
>   ExecuteNonQuery failed for Database 'Salesforce-Neptune'.  ---> 
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An
>   exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'select'.

C# (**does** work):

```
var server = new Server("serverName");
var sql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\code\test.sql");
var database = new Database(server, "myDatabase");
database.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
```

If I edit my `test.sql` file and put the entire query on a single line then my PowerShell script works.  What's the dealio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> or if there's some odd difference with reading a file in PowerShell that is causing me an issue

I believe this is because `Get-Content` reads files as an array of lines by default (just like `ReadAllLines()` in C# IIRC).

From V3 on, you can use the `-Raw` switch to disable this behavior, with V2 you have to use `[IO.File]::ReadAllText("file\path")`.

Comment: Ah!  That's exactly what the issue was.  That makes sense.  Thanks for your help.